# Traceback Distance Matrix

Tags: qgis, distance

I am using the QGIS Distance Matrix to calculate the distance of points along a line to that specific line. I used the tool before with 2 points layers and it worked well.

This time I created a points-chain layer of the line layer (same coord. system as the points layer, using the QChainage plug-in) and get the following traceback:

```
Log:

Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Distance matrix' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'INPUT' : 'G:/SMALLWORLD-GTO/working HPa/L8/BH/v3 evaluate/BHwelds_v2.shp|layername=BHwelds_v2', 'INPUT_FIELD' : 'Item_nr', 'MATRIX_TYPE' : 0, 'NEAREST_POINTS' : 1, 'OUTPUT' : 'memory:', 'TARGET' : 'G:/SMALLWORLD-GTO/working HPa/L8/BH/v3 evaluate/20181001_GTO_Pipe Segment Route_dline_CHAIN.shp|layername=20181001_GTO_Pipe Segment Route_dline_CHAIN', 'TARGET_FIELD' : 'cngmeters' }

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\PointDistance.py", line 141, in processAlgorithm
matType, nPoints, feedback)
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\PointDistance.py", line 183, in linearMatrix
index = QgsSpatialIndex(target_source.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setSubsetOfAttributes([]).setDestinationCrs(source.sourceCrs(), context.transformContext())), feedback)
Exception: unknown

Execution failed after 6.99 seconds

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Distance matrix' finished

Log end.
```

[image: Distance Matrix Traceback]

Questions are:

1) What does the traceback mean?

2) How can I solve/avoid it?